# How to get result from activity if started from Overlay?

Tags: java, android

How can i get the result back from an Activity if started from an Overlay e.g. I am using the following code:

```
Intent alertSett = new Intent(_ctx, AlertSettings.class); 

_ctx.startActivity(alertSett);

//set destination
setDestination();
```

I want to call the **setDestination();** based on the settings i received from AlertSettings Activity, there is no **startActivityForResult()** in context which seems ok because it'll trigger the overridden onActivityResult which is in Activity Class. Is there any other way to accomplish it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement sort of a callback mechanism by using[`BroadcastReceiver`](http://www.google.de/search?q=BroadcastReceiver).